# Why does this curl command return rss and not HTML?

Tags: curl, rss

if you go to www.sketchfemme.com using your browser you will get (view source):

```
<!doctype html>
   <html>

     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <title>SketchFemme Feature of the Day</title>
              .....
               <link href="/featured.rss" rel="alternate" title="SketchFemme Feature of the Day" type="application/rss+xml" />  
     </head>
```

But from mac terminal if I execute this command:

```
  curl sketchfemme.com -A "Mozilla/4.0" --trace-ascii - -L
```

I get back the xml content of the rss file.

I was expecting to see HTML using the curl command, why am I getting back XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl is adding `Accept: */*` header. This is causing your site to return with the RSS. (I have no idea *why* it is doing this). If you try it without the Accept header, then it works as you expect.

Comment: I had no idea `'Accept: */*'` would cause a auto discovery link on the page to be sent back ... how interesting.  I changed the command to curl localhost:5000 -H "Accept: text/html" -A "Mozilla/4.0" --trace-ascii - -L and it works just as you said.  Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a function of CURL. Your web server is doing this (when it probably shouldn't be)